# jquery-1.9.1 fires change event twice on select in Chrome

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure out why the change event fires twice for this select element:

```
<form name="contactform">
  <label for="requesttype">Request Type:</label>            
  <select name="requesttype" class="reqtype">
     <option value="1" selected>General Comment / Request</option>
     <option value="2">No Cost Services Quote</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

When using this jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".reqtype").change(function(){
        alert($(".reqtype option:selected").val());
    })
});
```

I double-checked that the only place I am using the class "reqtype" is in the select element.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tried your code..it gives alert only once..although try $(".reqtype").val() within alert and check

Comment: Very odd, indeed.  I made the suggested changes; however I am still getting two alerts.

Comment: perfectly valid code..!!

Comment: You have only one form on the page.?

Comment: OMG - Such a a bonehead mistake.  I have the .js file linked TWICE in the HTML header.  Thanks all for your time and help.

Answer (score 10):

Had a similar problem and tried all the solutions I could find.  The only one that worked for me was unbind before the change check (mentioned by DevPat above):

```js
jQuery("#wfselect").unbind(); 
jQuery("#wfselect").change(function() { getWFDetail(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this using .unbind() before binding the event handler results in a clean JS. You can refer to jQuery documentation